# How to send mail using phpmailer

Tags: php, email

I'm having trouble to send mail using `phpmailer`. Error appear is,

> 2016-02-16 13:20:14   Connection: opening to 103.8.25.18:465,
>   timeout=300,  options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false,
>   'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ), )
>   2016-02-16 13:20:35 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond. (10060) 2016-02-16
>   13:20:35  SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message
>   could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

If I test using direct from my localhost PC, it can send the mail but when I transfer the system to our office server, it won't send the mail. Below are the phpmailer codes;

```
require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.mydomain.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'myusername';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                // TCP port to connect to 
$mail->AddAddress('kamran@ktmparking.com.my');
$mail->addReplyTo('info@ktmparking.com.my', 'HR-KTMBCP');
$mail->setFrom('info@ktmparking.com.my', 'HR-KTMBCP'); 
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->isHTML(true);                             // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Leave Application';
$mail->Body    = 'example of message ';
$mail->AltBody = 'example of message'; 
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent'; 
}
```

Comment: Did you try port: 465 ?

Comment: Ping 103.8.25.18. what is the TTL

Comment: First you should have a look at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host

Comment: Already try port 465 but still the same. Unable to send the mail

Comment: Do i need to change anything at php.ini or sendmail.ini? I'm using xampp